# Google maps scheme give directions via latitude and longitude doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm trying to open the google maps app with a destination address in latitude and longitude. I tried like this:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=51.140566,4.441389k&directionsmode=driving"]];
```

But it gives me always that there are no routes.

Can point me out on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. I've had a extra k in my parameter from copy pasting the long and lats.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%@,%@&directionsmode=driving", latitude, longitude]]];
```